# How to break a sentence in python depending on fullstop '.'?

Tags: python, list

I writing a script in python in which I have the following string:

```
a = "write This is mango. write This is orange."
```

I want to break this string into sentences and then add each sentence as an item of a list so it becomes:

```
list = ['write This is mango.', 'write This is orange.']
```

I have tried using TextBlob but it is not reading it correctly.(Reads the whole string as one sentence).

Is there a simple way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) with *positive lookbehind* assertion:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "write This is mango. write This is orange."
>>> re.split(r'(?<=\w\.)\s', a)
['write This is mango.', 'write This is orange.']
```

If you want to *split* on more than one separator, say `.` and `,`, then use a character set in the assertion:

```
>>> a = "write This is mango. write This is orange. This is guava, and not pear."
>>> re.split(r'(?<=\w[,\.])\s', a)
['write This is mango.', 'write This is orange.', 'This is guava,', 'and not pear.']
```

---

On a side note, you should not use `list` as the name of a variable as this will *shadow* the builtin `list`.

Comment: Is it sensitive to any other special character other than '.' or anything like that?

Comment: @Elisha512 No worries. All [special characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) can be easily escaped as shown in my approach. Or you could site an example?

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Check out the .split() function here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

```
 a = "write This is mango. write This is orange."

 print a.split('.', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should look in to the NLTK for python.
Here's a sample from NLTK.org

```
>>> import nltk
>>> sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
... Arthur didn't feel very good."""
>>> tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
>>> tokens
['At', 'eight', "o'clock", 'on', 'Thursday', 'morning',
'Arthur', 'did', "n't", 'feel', 'very', 'good', '.']
>>> tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
>>> tagged[0:6]
[('At', 'IN'), ('eight', 'CD'), ("o'clock", 'JJ'), ('on', 'IN'),
('Thursday', 'NNP'), ('morning', 'NN')]
```

for your case you can do

```
import nltk
a = "write This is mango. write This is orange."
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You know about `string.split`? It can take a multicharacter split criterion:

```
>>> "wer. wef. rgo.".split(". ")
['wer', 'wef', 'rgo.']
```

But it's not very flexible about things like amount of white space. If you can't control how many spaces come after the full stop, I recommend regular expressions ("import re"). For that matter, you could just split on "." and clean up the white space at the front of each sentence and the empty list that you will get after the last ".".

Answer (score 0):

```html
<code>a.split()</code>
```

a.split() seems like a simple way of doing it, but you will eventually run into problems.

For example suppose you have

```
a = 'What is the price of the orange? \
It costs $1.39. \
Thank you! \
See you soon Mr. Meowgi.'
```

The a.split('.') would return:

```
a[0] = 'What is the price of the orange? It costs $1'
a[1] = '39'
a[2] = 'Thank you! See you soon Mr'
a[3] = 'Meowgi'
```

I am also not factoring in

- code snippets

  - e.g. 'The problem occured when I ran ./sen_split function. "a.str(" did not have a closing bracket.'
- Possible Names of Company's

  - e.g. 'I work for the Node.js company'
- etc.

This eventually boils down to English syntax. I would recommend looking into nltk module as Mike Tung pointed out.